# How can I change my console font to consolas in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, console

My console font is hard to read, I'd love to have consolas instead.  How can I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, turns out that it's easy.  Just right-click on the console to get the properties menu, then choose the font tab.

Comment: If it's that easy, it looks like you are running as administrator by default, which makes lots of things easy, not just for you, but anybody.